# Magento: ResourceModels throwing exceptions

Tags: magento

I'm trying to display the number of total number of sales for the currently viewing product on a block, so far i have, with the help of a stackoverflow thread:

```
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$productID = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product)->getId();
$productReport = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_sold_collection')->addOrderedQty()->addAttributeToFilter('id',$productID);
 foreach ($productReport as $product) {
    $product1 = $product->getOrderedQty();
    var_dump($product1);
}
```

I am able to load all sales quantities, but when i add the addAttributeToFilter

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816
```

It also happens if i pass $product directly, both are strings though. i don't know how to get the object i should pass to the addAttributeToFilter method, or if it should work with a string parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without trying it myself I suspect you need to filter by `entity_id` (and your second line is redundant).

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$productReport = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_sold_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $product->getId())
    ->addOrderedQty();
$qty = $productReport->getFirstItem()->getOrderedQty();
```

EDIT: Product and category collections also have an `addIdFilter()` method for that purpose, e.g
`->addIdFilter($product->getId())`
See `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addIdFilter()` for more details.

Comment: Not better, just different :)